# Selectize not showing data from ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, selectize.js

I'm using selectize js to have a search functionality and lets the user select multiple items based on the search. My problem is that the data is being retrieved properly but the data is not being shown by the control. Here's how I'm doing it.

The control:

```
<label>Skills Required</label>
<select id="skills-ddl"  class="form-control" placeholder="Search skills.." multiple ></select>
```

Js:

```
$(function () {
    var $select = $('#skills-ddl').selectize({
        valueField: 'Id',
        labelField: 'Name',
        load: function (query, callback) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/ClientProjects/GetSkills?keyword=' + encodeURIComponent(query),
                success: function (response) { console.log(response); $select.options = response; callback(response); }
            });
        }
    });

    var selectize = $select[0].selectize;

});
```

Here's a screenshot the data is there:
[image]

When I press backspace to make the search text box empty, the previous result is being displayed.
[image]

**EDIT:**

Here's how my response data looks like:

[image]

Comment: please post your `response` object you are getting inside success or dummy data with similar structure of `response` object.

Comment: Edited my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are missing `searchField` attribute due to which it is not able to understand which attribute it has to show in your dropdown when you type in it.

Try adding `searchField: 'Name'` after `labelField: 'Name',` which will give the filter names in the dropdown.

Your js code should look like below. Hope it will work for you

```
$(function () {
    var $select = $('#skills-ddl').selectize({
        valueField: 'Id',
        labelField: 'Name',
        searchField: 'Name',
        load: function (query, callback) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/ClientProjects/GetSkills?keyword=' + encodeURIComponent(query),
                success: function (response) { console.log(response); $select.options = response; callback(response); }
            });
        }
    });

    var selectize = $select[0].selectize;

});
```

Comment: I can't believe I missed that one. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

have not yet worked with selectize, but having a look at the docu I see that the load function should get only the callback function as parameter, no query parameter. Is this the problem?

https://github.com/selectize/selectize.js/blob/master/docs/api.md#methods_other

Regards,
Jochen